# esp32 ram fragmentation handling string

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have had a problem in the past with RAM fragmentation when using the String object so I tested a bit and switched to using the ArduinoJson library.

I have found my program to be stable with ArduinoJson however my code is longer. Therefore I would like to go back to using String and write my `answer` function by concatenating String variables.

Which of these methods is the best to avoid RAM fragmentation?

**Method one:**

```
void server answer (){
    request->send(200, "application/json", "{'data': "+variable+"});
}
```

**Method two:**

```
String Answer;
    
void server answer (){
    Answer = "{ 'data':" + variable + "}"
    request->send(200, "application/json", Answer);
}
```

**Method two-bis:**

```
void server answer (){
    String Answer;
    Answer = "{ 'data':" + variable + "}"
    request->send(200, "application/json", Answer);
}
```

**Method three:**

```
String cretateAnswer(){
    return "{ 'data': + variable + "};
}
void server answer (){
    request->send(200, "application/json", cretateAnswer());
}
```

I understand what is ram fragmentation, but I don't really understand when this happened and why using String, and how I can avoid it if my library want a String as answer????

P.S. I wrote this question "on the fly" so if json syntax is wrong or the \ before the ', sorry.

Comment: The `String` object might be claiming memory on the HEAP upon construction. To avoid RAM fragmentation - allocate and reuse a fixed size buffer, if that is possible. RAM fragmentation occurs on the heap (if your system has a heap?). Another option therefore is to explicitly allocate statically sized RAM on the stack (e.g. char my_string[128] ) and pass that to functions.

Comment: I presume this is C++? Please indicate which language and system you are programing for and what library is providing the String object.

Comment: @JimmyNJ `String` is from the Arduino standard library

Comment: There are many posts at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=string+memory+fragmentation

Comment: Method Three does not seem to be valid code. Pass `variable` in as an argument to `createAnswer`

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same. They are all doing exactly the same memory allocations to concatenate strings.

Either you use a buffer on the stack, and use `sprintf` to build your string

```
char buff[32];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "{ \"data\":%d}", variable);
request->send(200, "application/json", buff);
```

or don't concatenate at all and just send each part right away.

```
AsyncResponseStream *response = request->beginResponseStream("application/json");
response->print("{ \"data\":");
response->print(variable);
response->print("}");
request->send(response);
```

or just

```
AsyncResponseStream *response = request->beginResponseStream("application/json");
response->printf("{ \"data\":%d}", variable);
request->send(response);
```

Comment: yes, seems to be better but ta this point I can use https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#json-body-handling-with-arduinojson

what I don't understand what chance concatening String to make multiple response->print

Should this function concatening String the same?